# Events and exceptions in 3-layer architecture

Tags: vb.net, exception, architecture, event-handling, layer

I have another question considering events and exceptions

A small introduction to my project: I'm working in a 3 layer architecture, so I have a GUI(form), BLL(Business logic layer) and a DAL(data acces layer).

So my GUI is linked to a BLL which is connected to several DAL classes. For example my BLL has a class clsCSV (which reads and writes CSV files)

I now want to raise events and/or catch exceptions from this class to inform the user and log exceptions. There are 3 events: "ErrorLoad", "ErrorWrite", "Ready"

```
Public Class clsCSV

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Function Load(sFilePath As String)
    Dim oFileHelper As New DelimitedFileEngine(Of clsItem)
    Dim oList As New List(Of clsItem)

    ' Load a CSV file
    Try
        oList = oFileHelper.ReadFileAsList(sFilePath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'RaiseEvent ErrorLoad("")
        clsErrorLog.Log(ex)
    Finally

    End Try

    ' If the list is empty return nothing
    If Not IsNothing(oList) Then
        Return oList
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If


End Function

Public Sub Write(sFilePath As String, oList As List(Of clsTranslatedItem))
    Dim oFileHelper As New DelimitedFileEngine(Of clsTranslatedItem)

    oFileHelper.WriteFile(sFilePath, oList)
    RaiseEvent Ready()
End Sub

Public Event ErrorLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Public Event ErrorWrite(sMessage As String)

Public Event Ready()
```

End Class

There is a try-catch in my public sub load which catches any exception and logs it to a text file by calling clsErrorLog.log(ex) which then calls this class and logs the error:

```
Public Shared Sub Log(ex As Exception)

    Try
        Dim oBestand As New System.IO.StreamWriter(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\ErrorLog.txt", True)

        If Not IsNothing(oBestand) Then
            oBestand.WriteLine("")
            oBestand.WriteLine(My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToString)

            oBestand.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            oBestand.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
            oBestand.WriteLine("_________________________________________")
            oBestand.Close()
        End If

    Catch exc As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

This works fine, but now I want to inform the user that an error occured, so I was thinking to raise an event called "ErrorLoad" (in clsCSV) and catch this in my BLL. But what can I do then? Add a sub that handles this event, which then raises an event in the BLL, caught by the GUI? or is this a long way to this?

I also want to do this for the other events offcourse. But the whole event system in the layered architecture is a bit confusing.

Anyone who can enlighten me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. Doesn't just `Throw` do what you want?

Comment: Well, I want to 'throw' custom messages to the GUI, because the full message gets logged anyway and I can't just type Throw ("An error occurred while loading the CSV")

Comment: Why not? You can do something like `Throw New Exception("Load Error)` and catch it up in your gui

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand, this breaks my solution. How can I catch this exception in the GUI ?

Comment: The same way as you do it always: With a `Try/Catch`

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere, when the error occurs and the solution is in the catch, you can acutally do messagebox.show("Help"). I thought this was impossible due to thread crossing? That's why I wanted to do this with the events.

Comment: So with try catches it would look like (try catch in try catch in try catch);
GUI try
BLL Try
             CSV Try
             Catch
             throw new exception
        catch
Catch exception
Messagebox
End Try

Isn't this very heavy for processing times?

Comment: Being in a different layer does not mean you are in a different thread. Of course you can show a message here unless you are running it in a diferent thread. But usually this is the case (or should be, loading data in a different thread is something common).

Comment: So showing messageboxes in catches is not thread crossing? 
But changing labels would be since these are in the form thread right?

Comment: I think you have to study some concepts. In a `Catch` you can access a label for example...as long you have access to that label in the class. So, if in your form's code you have a `Try/Catch`, in the catch part you can change a label,but in the BLL you can't because that class does not have access to that label, not because it's in a different thread. Other thing is when you are in a separate thread of the UI,that's a different situation

Comment: Ah I see. I'm going to look up a bit more about threads, thanks!
I saw some of it in school a while ago, but things get confusing sometimes. I'm now getting into some more evolved projects for my work.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the implementation details of your UI, I can only give you some general advice.

You need some kind of two directional communication between your GUI and your BLL. For example in WPF this is usually done using [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and the event it defines.

So the BLL raises a event and the GUI is listening. The basically only has the task of informing the GUI that it has to check a specific property or function or anything like this from the BLL. The rest is up to the GUI to do so and inform the user.

I wouldn't do that using exceptions. These are there to handle the error path of specific functions. This path is done once your BLL noticed the error and prepared it for the UI handling.

Comment: The thing is, the events are coming from my DAL classes, telling the BLL they failed. Should I then just raise an event from the BLL again, to notify the GUI? I feel like this is not a very efficient way to do this?

Comment: The BLL receives the exact error. It fetches the proper message for the UI and once it is done it reports to the UI: *a* error has happend, show *this* message to the user. It does not need to receive more details about the error.

Comment: So this is a correct way to do this? So for my event Ready() there is a ReadyHandler in my BLL calling another event, which is handled in my GUI.

Comment: That is one way to do it. It is the one with the clearest separation between the layers. Creating a application with clear separation between the layers is never the most efficient way to do things. But you get a much better maintainability.